# Converting Decimal hours to minutes in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, sql-server-2012

I have a decimal hour (`logged_hours`) column and its value in my table. I want to calculate this decimal hour value into minutes in SQL Server 2012.

```
logged_hours
------------
08.0000
09.0000
12.0000
```

Comment: Why is this *not* just multiplication..? When you tried multiplication, why didn't it work? I feel like there's something we're not being told here (such as that `logged_hours` is a `varchar`, and thus you got an error when you tried to multiply it).

Answer (score 2):

You can multiply by 60:

```
select logged_hours * 60 as logged_minutes
```

Comment: does this work on decimal precision as well?